# Alternative way to lessen code

Tags: javascript, php

I need some help, is there a way in order to lessen my code? This problem occurs expecially when I use quite long arrays and I'd like to know if there is a way to make them shorter? Thanks.

```
$query = "SELECT question,answer FROM easy_ques;";
    $retval = $conn->query($query);

     while($row = $retval->fetch_assoc()) {
            $quest[] = $row['question'];
            $ans[] = $row['answer'];
        }

        echo "<script>";

        echo "var answer = ['$ans[0]','$ans[1]','$ans[2]','$ans[3]','$ans[4]','$ans[5]','$ans[6]','$ans[7]','$ans[8]','$ans[9]','$ans[10]','$ans[11]','$ans[12]','$ans[13]','$ans[14]','$ans[15]','$ans[16]','$ans[17]','$ans[18]','$ans[19]','$ans[20]','$ans[21]','$ans[22]','$ans[23]','$ans[24]','$ans[25]','$ans[26]','$ans[27]','$ans[28]','$ans[29]','$ans[30]','$ans[31]','$ans[32]','$ans[33]','$ans[34]'];";

        echo "var question = ['$quest[0]','$quest[1]','$quest[2]','$quest[3]','$quest[4]','$quest[5]','$quest[6]','$quest[7]','$quest[8]','$quest[9]','$quest[10]','$quest[11]','$quest[12]','$quest[13]','$quest[14]','$quest[15]','$quest[16]','$quest[17]','$quest[18]','$quest[19]','$quest[20]','$quest[21]','$quest[22]','$quest[23]','$quest[24]','$quest[25]','$quest[26]','$quest[27]','$quest[28]','$quest[29]','$quest[30]','$quest[31]','$quest[32]','$quest[33]','$quest[34]'];";

        echo"</script>";
```

Comment: use the for loop, luke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this? It's not length-dependant and produces readable code.

```
$query = "SELECT question,answer FROM easy_ques;";
$retval = $conn->query($query);

echo "<script>\n";

echo "var answer = new Array();\n";
echo "var question = new Array();\n";

while($row = $retval->fetch_assoc())
{
     echo "answer.push('{$row['answer']}');\n";
     echo "question.push('{$row['question']}');\n";
}

echo"</script>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this approach too:

```
$row = $retval->fetch_assoc();

$questions = "'" . $row['question'] . "'";
$answers = "'" . $row['answer'] . "'";

 while($row = $retval->fetch_assoc()) {
        $questions = $questions . ",'" . $row['question'] . "'";
        $answers = $answers . ",'" . $row['answer'] . "'";
 }

 echo "<script>";

 echo "var answer = [$answers];";

 echo "var question = [$questions];";

 echo "</script>";
```

Answer (score 0):

it would be:

```
$row = mysqli_num_rows($result);

for($i = 0; $i<$row; $i++)
{
 var answer = $ans[i];
var question= $quest[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method. Replace 35 with the length of your variable (ans/quests)

```
var newString = "";
var stringArr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 35; i++) {
  stringArr.push("$ans'[" + i + "]'")
}
var newString = "var answer = [" + stringArr.join(", ") + "];";

echo newString;
```